# PHP : edit issued invoice

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, payment-processing

I'm implementing invoice system and table of my app.lets say an invoice is issued by the site admin. then customer click on the payment link and get forwarded to payment Gateway. **at the same time** admin find out the price is not correct and decide to edit the price but customer is already on the payment gateway page and is paying based on the previous price. how can i prevent this conflict or issue?

Comment: The only way to stop this is to compare the price in the db v.s. the price from the checkout in order to ensure that they're the same. If they're not, then notify the user.

Comment: Business rule should be that you can't change invoice, once it's created. You can create a credit note which is a separate document.

Comment: Changing the price is not really recommended since it might cause authorization issues with data tampering.

Answer (score 0):

when user redirected from payment gateway you should be compare your price to his paid price if both are same then continue otherwise alert the user regarding admin changes for price.